# Why/How does this sqrt term work? The inverse of a fraction in a sqrt

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does this term work?

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}} = \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}
$$

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator (on the left) by $\sqrt l$.

Comment: Is there a reason for `g` and `l`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll probably for gravity and length. It looks like a quantity you frequently encounter in periodic motion.

Comment: @graydad yeah, if the variables represent gravity and length, then this expression represents a frequency, since it has the dimensions of [1/time]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two things happening here. One is that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$$ for all nonnegative real numbers where $b \neq 0$. Second is that $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c}$$ for all real numbers where $b,c,d \neq 0$. For your problem, let $a=b=1$, and $c=\sqrt{g},d = \sqrt{l}$. The equality follows.

Comment: Welp, now I got it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: For your second your say it is true when $b$ and $c$ are different from $0$, but what about $d$?

Comment: @KristofferRyhl I debated including that in there. Certainly if it were just $\frac{c}{d}$ I would want to say that. I'll include it to be safe.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not true when $d=0$, so it's a good idea to leave it in.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl There is nothing wrong with having $d=0$ in the quantity $\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c}$.

Comment: No, that equation is well defined for $d=0$, but the other is not. $$\text{undefined}\ne\frac ab\cdot\frac 0c$$

Comment: Again, it is probably better to include $d\neq 0$ to avoid any uncertainty. If I knew $\frac{a}{b}\cdot {d}{c} = 0$ I'd be inclined to define $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} \equiv 0$

Comment: It does not hold for all real numbers with $b\neq 0$. Consider $(a,b)=(1,-1)$. Change that to 'for all non-negative numbers where $b\neq 0$'.

Answer (score 9):

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and $\frac{1}{a/b}=b/a$

Comment: In one regard this is superior to many of the other answers, in that it doesn't rely on $\sqrt{l}$ or $\sqrt{g}$ being well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{g}{l}}} = \dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} =   \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{0}}{\left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{0-\frac{1}{2}} =\left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \left(\left(\dfrac{g}{l}\right)^{-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \left(\dfrac{l}{g}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} =  \sqrt{\dfrac{l}{g}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If both $g,l\ne 0$, you apply roots property $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ and reals ratios property $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)}=\frac{d}{c}$, and get:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}}=
\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{g}}{\sqrt{l}}\right)}=
\frac{\sqrt{l}}{\sqrt{g}}=
\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

With $l \cdot g \neq 0$

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}} = \frac{1\times\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}\times\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}}= \frac{\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}\times\frac{l}{g}}} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}}{1} = \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}
$$